# getElementById not working - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, logic, getelementbyid

**JavaScript**

```
var stuAverage;
function calcAvg(gradeInfo)
   {
    finalExam = document.getElementById("finalExam").value;
    homework = document.getElementById("homework").value;
    projects = document.getElementById("projects").value;
    stuAverage = (finalExam * .1) + (homework * .4) + (projects * .5);
    document.getElementById("stuAverage").value=stuAverage;
    alert("Your average is " + stuAverage);
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" name="gradeInfo">
<p>
Enter Final Exam Grade:
<input type="text" name="finalExam" size="4" /><br />
Enter Homework Grade:
<input type="text" name="homework" size="4" /><br />
Enter Projects Grade:
<input type="text" name="projects" size="4" /><br />
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="AVERAGE" onclick="calcAvg(gradeInfo)" />
<input type="button" value="CLEAR" onclick="clearData(gradeInfo)" />
<br /><br />
Your Average is:
<input type="text" name="stuAverage" size="4" /><br />
</p>
</form>
```

Trying to figure out how to use the getElementById with DOM but I'm having trouble understanding the logic.

The CLEAR function works but again, I'd wanna be using getElementById to make that work preferably.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't see any HTML elements with those ids. Only names.

Comment: @david.pfx no, it looks like I'm new to the getElementById concept and needed a small clarification. Didn't ask anyone to do it for me, but I appreciate the attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `id` not `name` (that's why it's called `getElementById`) so

```
<input type="text" id="finalExam" name="finalExam" size="4" /><br />
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="finalExam" size="4" /><br />
```

not

```
<input type="text" name="finalExam" size="4" /><br />
```

Comment: I understand now, thanks for explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing id attribute.

try id="finalExam" in your input